# URL in Gmail Alias

Tags: url, gmail, alias

At our company, we are working with several aliases. The current situation is that one team of 10 has two aliases. In SalesForce, they would like to put the link to specific emails so that anybody out of the team can open an e-mail related to a claim for instance.

In the e-mail's link, there's the "/u/0" part that identifies the mail gmail account (firstname.lastname@...), but it seems that the aliases have a different number for everybody.

So to be clear when they open the same mail in the shared alias, the e-mail ID stays the same in the URL (logic) but the digit after the "/u/" changes for everybody.

Is there a way to generate a URL that will open the e-mail independently of the person that clicks on the URL ?

Edit:

I'll try to be clearer. Our Customer Service Center employees all have two e-mail adresses: an individual one, and a delegated one. Customers will send e-mails to the delegated one (accessible by all employees). So what we would like to do is copy the link of the e-mail into SalesForce so that any employee (who has access to the delegated gmail) can check the e-mail. But, as explained above, as the individual gmail adress is always identified by a "0" after the "/u/" chain in the URL:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/**0**/#inbox/156b821f776b6d4a

the delegated gmail adress is identified by a number that differs depending on the person. So employee A will have "/u/**144**/" as link to the delegated gmail, another employee will have "u/**345**/ as link to the delegated gmail. This makes it impossible to access the e-mail by clicking the link...

Hope this little case-study makes the issue clearer.

Thanks in advance

Julien

Comment: Hi Julien - can you give examples of how you're using these URLs, and show more clearly what you want to happen but what is going wrong? If you [edit] your question with some clarification, it will make it easier to answer.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Hello Vince, thanks for your answer. I've added a little more context to my question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to do this too.

I think the only way (outside of paying for the Google business email system) is to have a database of user IDs that link to each user's gmail delegate URL.

I have a system that allows about 6 or 7 users to login, however they all share the login details (it's a small website, with no important information stored). I will have to force them all to have separate login details, and then have a lookup for their gmail delegate URL.

If you have a lot of staff, then you'd have to get their buy-in. Maybe send a global email around that links to a simple web form, that takes them through how to enter their delegate URL. Then store this in a database, with their own personal email (the other gmail account). You should make the form validation strict, so no garbage gets entered. For users who get stuck (fail validation for entering a valid gmail delegate URL), ask them to email support. 95% of staff should be able to handle this. The other 5% would just be an exercise in patience, in getting the rest of the data.